# Can't debug my Android library if the class was created with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aar

I created an Android library that was originally coded with Java and it outputs an `.aar` file that I use in some of my projects.

When I include this lib in a project (an Android project created with Kotlin) and I decide to debug the code in this project, when the debugger reaches a line containing a library's class, it successfully steps into the class and I can see the source code of the class while I'm debugging it. I can continue the debug line by line inside the lib's class and everything works as expected.

However, I recently decided to convert this library to Kotlin but now, when the debugger reaches one of the lib's class and I step into the class to continue debugging there, I can no longer see the entire source code. I can only see the method signatures, but without the method definitions. I see only things like:

```kotlin
public class ClassA {
    public fun function1(): kotlin.Unit

    public fun function2(): kotlin.Unit

    public fun function3(): kotlin.Unit
}
```

I didn't do any else in the library's project settings. I simply converted the files from `.java` to `.kt`.

Here are some things that I tried so far to solve this problem:

- I confirmed that I included Kotlin's standard lib in the dependencies list of the `build.gradle` file in the library.
- I disabled ProGuard (it has never been a problem, but I removed it just in case).
- I disabled code minification (it has never been a problem too, but at this point I'm willing to try anything).

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is the project that uses the library configured to use Kotlin?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the second paragraph, the project that uses the lib is a Kotlin one.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @hmartinezd Unfortunately no. But I found a few threads in Jetbrains bug reporting site about this same issue. It seems to be a well known problem for many years :(

Comment: Got same issue. We prefer to write all libraries in JAVA until there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

While debugging when it prompt "Choose Sources", Click on that option

[image]

and select the "main" folder of the library module from your local codebase of the library

[image]

Now try to debug (by choosing 'step into' option etc), the debugger should able to get the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Even if it worked, I would rather not have to distribute the source code together with the lib binaries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, saved a lot of debugging time